# EasyPHP & Virtual Host Manager (Windows 10)

Tags: php, localhost, virtualhost, development-environment, easyphp

I've installed EasyPHP and Virtual Host Manager - got it up and running, created a virtual host, pointed it to the directory to where i have my website stored. It's on the D Drive however when i click on the virtual host that i've created it points to a directory inside where the installation took place for EasyPHP as shown below;

[image: EasyPHP Admin]

Browsing the localhost development URL shows this;
[image]

So the only way i got it working was to dump the site folder inside the projects folder and it worked. Strange. Anyone know how i can get it to load from the virtual host URL and directory?

Comment: I know that this is outdated topic. When you try to access virtual host but target directory does not exists anymore, then you get local web directory from EasyPHP. Check do really exists directory C:\localweb\websites\mjcoder_local\public_html\

Comment: I just got it to work with EasyPHP version 16.1.